# Python regex Doesn't Match a Simple Pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a very simple pattern using Python's regex package (I am new to regex). I don't understand the following behavior:

```
import regex
regex.match('economy', 'promising.\n\nARTICLE 4\n\nECONOMY The economy')
```

or

```
regex.match('ARTICLE', 'promising.\n\nARTICLE 4\n\nECONOMY The economy')
```

doesn't match anything. Of course if I do

`regex.match('economy', 'economy')`

it does it. Why that is the case?
Also, if I want to match case sensitive 'ARTCLE' in the above example, what should be right way to do it?
I am usng 2016.1.10 version of regex.

Answer (score 0):

`match` looks for a match at the start of the string. If you want to match other than the start you need to use `search`.

I don't have `regex` installed here but it should be the same as `re`.

```
>>> re.search('economy', 'promising.\n\nARTICLE 4\n\nECONOMY The economy')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(35, 42), match='economy'>
```

Comment: I wonder why match is designed in such a manner though, when search is so much more robust